# Django password reset login link

Tags: django, passwords, django-admin

I'm setting up password_reset for the admin, using the default templates, and it's all working well except for the last login link on password_reset_complete screen. I would like it to redirect to the admin login, but it's redirecting to accounts/login, which is the default url. I'm thinking I would want the accounts/login url to be different from the admin/login url if I ever needed a login that wasn't for the admin.

In the documentation it looks like there's a redirect_to_login function, but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to use it. It also looks like there's a current app argument for password_reset_complete, but my syntax isn't right if I try to add it.
I want to redirect to the admin login.

Here's what I have so far:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    ('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/password_reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', dict(is_admin_site=True), name="admin_password_reset"),
    url(r'^admin/password_reset_done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^admin/password_reset_confirm/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^admin/password_reset_complete/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', name='password_reset_complete'),
    #(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),     
    url(r'^admin/login/', admin.site.login, name='login')
)
```

Comment: Pure speculation - Move the last url pattern - `url(r'^admin/login/', admin.site.login, name='login')` above `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`

Comment: This doesn't work, as it needs that line to be a valid url. I can make it work the way I want it to by setting login_url to /admin/ in settings, but I think it would be more appropriate to pass the name of the admin app to the password_reset_complete view. I haven't been able to do this though. It's confusing in that there is an "is_admin" parameter in the password_reset view, but I'm not sure how to specify it on the login link except this way, which doesn't feel like it's as flexible as I'd like it to be.